# Can a sequence of operators with trace-class norm 1 have a trace that converges absolutely to 0?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, trace

Does there exist a sequence of (non-normal) trace-class operators $X_n$ such that in some ONB $\{ v_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ we have 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \vert \langle v_i, X_n v_i \rangle \vert \to 0 \text{  as } n \to \infty
\end{align*}
and at the same time $\vert \vert X_n \vert \vert_{tc} = 1 $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You can probably even take $X_n = X$ independent of $n$ such that $\langle v_i, X v_i\rangle =0$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can consider $X_{ij}^n = 1_{i = j = n}$.